# Python - converting imports to module format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python package that is structured using imports as if a script is run from the root of the package. So the structure looks something like this:

```
foo/
    script.py
    bar/
        import_a.py
    bar_two/
        import_b.py
```

And the imports within the lower level packages, for example in import_b.py are structured like

```
from bar import import_a
```

Obviously this breaks if you want to re-structure this as a package instead of running scripts from the root directory. I need to re-do all the import statements, and add __init__.py files to each subdirectory (this is in python 2.7 as I have to use this with a pre-existing [ros kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic) repo, whereas the initial repo was in python 3).

My question is twofold: is there an easy method / script to convert the imports, and is there some way of auto-generating the corresponding __init__.py files?

Answer (score -1):

From the perspective of Python 2.7 this is not even a package since it misses all the `__init__.py` files (and namespace packages didn't exist back then). So there's not way around creating these `__init__.py` files. But that should be relatively easy. You can use the following Python snippet from the root of the (to-be-)package:

```
import os

for item in os.walk('.'):
    path = item[0]
    with open(os.path.join(path, '__init__.py'), 'w') as fh:
        pass
```

For the modification of import statements there's a way around it. When importing the package you can add the file path of the root `__init__.py` script to `sys.path`. That is you can add the following code to `foo/__init__.py` at the very top:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.split(__file__)[0])
```

That way all imports can be resolved by searching that directory.